# Group elements based on two parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a list of objects, with two parameters, `param1`, and `param2`, defined by this class:

```
Class test
    public name
    Public param1
    Public param2
End Class
```

The aim is to group all objects with the same param1 and param2, for further processing.

I have tried to do it using LINQ, and the groupBy feature, but I can't make it work, despite my best efforts.

I have copied my work in a fiddle for clarity: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n19PRv

The expected output is:

```
num0 (-> num1 is in the same group, it is not displayed)
num2
num3
num4
```

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for comparable [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767) is

```
New With { Key .param1 = c.param1, Key .param2 = c.param2 }
```

where `Key` is added in front of all properties that are compared. A bit easier with `Tuple`:

```
For Each myGroup In list.ToLookup(Function(c) Tuple.Create(c.param1, c.param2))
```

(`GroupBy` uses `LookUp` to get the groups)

Answer (score 0):

When using VB.NET, you need to tell the compiler which properties of the anonymous type are used when comparing for equality:

> The Key keyword enables you to specify behavior for properties of anonymous types. Only properties you designate as key properties participate in tests of equality between anonymous type instances, or calculation of hash code values. The values of key properties cannot be changed.

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531349.aspx) for details.

In order to make your sample work, you only need to add the `Key` keyword in front of the properties of the anonymous type:

```
From c In list Group c _
By Key = New With { Key c.param1, Key c.param2} Into Group select group
```